How to generate the index.xml file for a quarto website?
I have initialized the YML in index.qmd as explained by the options section for quarto websites:
---
title: "Datos y Leyendas"
listing:
  feed: 
    items: 5
    type: partial
    language: es
  contents: posts/**/*.qmd
  sort: "date desc"
  type: default
  categories: true
  sort-ui: false
  filter-ui: false
  fields: [image, date, title, reading-time, description, categories]
page-layout: full
title-block-banner: false
comments: false
toc: false
---

Then, this is an extract from my _quarto.yml:
project:
  type: website

lang: es

website:
  title: "Diabb Zegpi"
  site-url: https://zegpi.com
  navbar:
    logo: dyl-light.svg
    right:
      - icon: rss
        href: index.xml

The issue is index.qmd does not generate index.xml, thus the RSS feed is not working. What is the propoer way of "turning on" the .xml generation?

It works for me, index.xml gets created in the _site folder.

Then I have to add the _site folder to resources?

I did not add it manually. I created a new project, included your codes (ignoring e.g. the .svg) and this worked ...

Then the path to index.xml is _site/index.xml or just index.xml?

_site/index.xml is the path.

Also, I've seen that .gitignore is listing the _site folder, so I think I should remove it from the list. Is this correct?

Yes, you probably want to have this not seen by .gitignore.
